# Swift: Core Data Display unique records in tableview

Tags: swift, tableview, fetch

I am trying to display only unique "names" from my Core Data entity called "Persons". From this, I am currently fetching out from the "name" attribute, along with "age", "description" and "country". However, I want it to only display one instance of each name (only unique names), instead of having two "Bob", three "Sara" and seven "Ali". I am trying to only show the unique names in the "nameLabel" in my cell, while having the latest record of "date added" in the other table view cell label. So this is basically what I want to achieve:

Andreas - 12/13/2015
Ali - 10/10/2015
John - 05/04/2015

etc..

//Even though maybe 5 Andreas' already exist, I want to display only one, but the latest "Date" added.

Here is the code I currently have, which works - but does not filter anything.

My global variables:

```
var Names : [NSManagedObject] = []
var Dates : [NSManagedObject] = []
```

In my ViewDidLoad:

```
let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = delegate.managedObjectContext


        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Persons")

        var err:NSError?

        do {

            Names = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
            Dates = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [NSManagedObject]

        } catch let err1 as NSError {
            err = err1
        }

        if err != nil {
            print("Problem loading data..")
        }
```

In my tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
 let Name = Names[indexPath.row]
        let DateAdded = Dates[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


    if Name.valueForKey("name") != nil {
        cell.nameLabel!.text = Name.valueForKey("name") as! String
    } else {
        cell.nameLabel!.text = ""
    }
    if DateAdded.valueForKey("date") != nil {
        cell.dateLabel!.text = DateAdded.valueForKey("date") as! String
    } else {
        cell.dateLabel!.text = ""
    }


    return cell
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have struggled with this for weeks now, trying to solve this "mystery".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but you should be using aggregate functions to get what you want.  Here's what it should look like.  You might have to tweak it a bit, but this should work.

```
func fetchLastUpdateDates(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [String: NSDate] {
    var namesWithDates = [String: NSDate]()

    var properties = [AnyObject]()

    // retrieve the name value in the results
    properties.append("name")

    // retrieve the max value of date in the aggregate
    let latestDateDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
    latestDateDescription.name = "LastDate"
    latestDateDescription.expression = NSExpression(format: "@max.date")
    latestDateDescription.expressionResultType = .DateAttributeType
    properties.append(latestDateDescription)

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Persons")
    // aggregate by "name" - results in one entry per name
    request.propertiesToGroupBy = ["name"]

    // need to use the "dictionary" result type because aggregate doesn't represent an actual record
    request.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
    request.propertiesToFetch = properties

    context.performBlockAndWait {
        do {
            if let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                // convert the results in to name-date dictionary
                for result in results {
                    if let name = result["name"] as? String, date = result["LastDate"] as? NSDate {
                        namesWithDates[name] = date
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch _ {
            // handle your errors here
        }
    }
    return namesWithDates
}
```

You don't really need to covert the results into `name-date` dictionary and can also add `sortDescriptors` to `request` so that the list is sorted as desired.  But that's is up to you.